# ShowDialog not showing dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I want to show other form with loading gif while executing something async. Any ideas why first `TowerPinsVisu` is executing and after that the `ShowDialog`?

```
private void RunTasks()
    {
         var tskShowLoadingForm=new Task(() => {
         loadingForm.ShowDialog("OPTIMIZING...");
         });
         tskShowLoadingForm.Start();
         var tskVisualizeTowerPins = new Task(() => TowerPinsVisu());
         tskVisualizeTowerPins.Start();
    }

  public void ShowDialog(string text)
        {
            lblLoadingInfo.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lblLoadingInfo.Content = text);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> ShowDialog());
        }
```

Comment: that's obvious. it's because you are not waiting for the task to finish. your design is completely wrong by the way. there is absolutely zero benefit of running a task which will be completely invoked by the dispatcher.

Comment: whatever it is that you are running in the loadingForm that needs to be run asynchronously, "THAT" should be in a task not the "FORM"

Comment: When I don't invoke it I get the following error 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

Comment: of-course you will get thread exception. My point is there is no point in running invoked operations in another thread, all the invoked operations will run in the thread which owns the dispatcher which is the main thread. do you get it? zero benefit from task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your flow, you have to run `TowerPinsVisu()`on a background thread using `Task.Run`. While this thread is running you can then show the dialog.
You can attach a continuation to the `Task`, which will be executed once the `Task` has run to completion. By passing the UI thread's `SynchronizationContext` to the contuation, you can force this continuation to execute on the UI thread (which is necessary to close the dialog:

```
// If this method executes on the UI thread...
private void RunTasks()
{
  // Start a background thread and continue immediately to show the modal screen.
  Task.Run(TowerPinsVisu)
    .ContinueWith(task => loadingForm.Close(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

  loadingForm.ShowDialog("OPTIMIZING...");
}

// ...then this method will too => No need to use a Dispatcher at this point
public void ShowDialog(string text)
{
  lblLoadingInfo.Content = text;
  ShowDialog();
}
```